# Angular Favicon not rendering in tab?

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, browser, favicon

In this site:

https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/

The Favicon renders as the Angular icon.  If I go into developer tools and right click on the favicon link, and select "Open in new tab", it opens this:

https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/favicon.ico

And that shows the right icon.  Any ideas on why it's not showing the right icon in the tab?

Comment: For me its showing the right icon. Maybe a cache issue?

Comment: Hmmm ... Interesting ... Thanks for checking.  I opened it up in Firefox as well, and it still showed the wrong icon, but when I try Brave it shows the right one.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also tried incognito mode in both firefox and chrome, and both still showed the wrong icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a cache, you can see here that it displayed when I clicked the first URL

[image]

You can try with a different browser or incognito mode to avoid cache